# altair translate map (move map)

Tags: python, altair

I have an altair world map with some data projected on it (gps-points).
I can scale the map, but when I translate the map (moving it) then I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

When i delete the part:

```
translate=[100, 550]
```

the map is shown, but i wanna show a different zone of the world.
Why is this error?

This is my code for displaying the map:

```
# World background
world = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url, 'countries')
background = alt.Chart(world).mark_geoshape(fill='lightgray', 
stroke='white').properties(width=800,height=800).project(type='mercator', scale=300, 
translate=[100, 550])

# gps position *.jpg photos
points = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
latitude='latitude',
longitude='longitude',
color=alt.value('steelblue'),
tooltip=['naam']
).project(scale=300)

st.altair_chart(background + points, use_container_width=True)
```

Comment: You are setting a list where is expected a dict. As the complete error is not available,  is not possible say more

Comment: According to: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/projections/#properties the translation offset is a two-element array.

Comment: To center on a specific location, set `center=[lat,lon]`. Also, translate specifies the pixel coordinates of where to project on the map layout. In your example, for an area of 800 pixels in height and width, you would center it at 100 pixels in width and 500 pixels in height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have an unsupported version of `jsonschema`; see https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2496

If you `pip install jsonschema<4.0`, the chart should work as written. Alternatively, you can update to an Altair version newer than 4.1 (currently 4.2.0.rc1 is available, and the final 4.2.0 release should happen soon).